# mongodumpができません。Failed: can't create session: failed to connect to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

mongodumpを試みていますが、下記のエラーになり、ネットでいくら探っても解決策が見当たらない状況です。もし解決策をおわかりでしたら教えていただけませんか？ちなみにわたくしのmongodbのバージョン情報等はさらに下に記載しています。

### 実行結果

```
C:\Users\alexa>mongodump -u root -p ****** -d sample -o C:\mongodb\backup\yyyymmdd

2024-02-09T20:12:26.414+0900 Failed: can't create session: failed to connect to mongodb://localhost/: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

### 環境情報

```
C:\Users\alexa>mongod --version

db version v7.0.5

Build Info: {

"version": "7.0.5",

"gitVersion": "7809d71e84e314b497f282ea8aa06d7ded3eb205",

"modules": [],

"allocator": "tcmalloc",

"environment": {

    "distmod": "windows",

    "distarch": "x86_64",

    "target_arch": "x86_64"

}
}

C:\Users\alexa>mongodump --version

mongodump version: 100.9.4

git version: ce6af0fefca324ad5d9cb689d335130f48c99699

Go version: go1.20.12

os: windows

arch: amd64

compiler: gc

C:\Users\alexa>mongosh --version

2.1.3
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/5by437jnemd28d) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)